# Error with my model's legs

Tags: modeling, mesh, subdivision-surface

Ok so, basically I have this error where my model's legs aren't connecting

may someone let me know how to fix it?

[image: Error with legs]

Comment: Hello, maybe an inner face that you need to delete? Or overlapping vertices?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the vertices in the knee area are duplicated, and the top ones are separated from the bottom ones. Furthermore it looks like the top part is closed with a face towards the knee while the bottom part is open to the top.

To fix this:

1. Go into *Edit Mode* and select all with <kbd>A</kbd>.

   [image: select all]
2. Now press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge* > *By Distance*.

   [image: merge by distance]

   If the *Merge* operation shows "Removed 0 vertice(s)" in the status bar at the bottom, then probably the *Merge Distance* was too small and the vertices are further apart. Increase this value very carefully, until the status bar shows a number of vertices > 0 to be removed (presumably 4 in your case). If you increase the value too much, other parts of the mesh might get merged as well although they are supposed to be separate.

   [image: number of removed vertices]
3. It should already look better now. But there is still a face inside the mesh. You can either select it in *Face Select* mode with *X-Ray* enabled by directly clicking it or to make sure you get all possible inside faces, from the viewport menu choose *Select* > *Select All by Trait* > *Interior Faces*.

   [image: select interior faces]
4. All faces on the inside of the mesh should be selected now and you can hit <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete* > *Faces*.

   [image: delete face(s)]

Comment: Now it looks like this its upper leg is square-ish: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m65OR.png

Comment: It also looks like there are edges going inside from the corner vertices, so it's not one interior face but four triangles going from the center to the outward edges. That's a good example where using the menu _Select Interior Faces_ comes in handy. Looking at it again I think these triangles weren't there before. Did you **Merge > By Distance** or **Merge > At Center**?

Comment: I did distance I think.